# Is it possible to disable an autoconfiguration class from another autoconfiguration class in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a data access library and would like to be able to include it as a dependency in other projects with minimal configuration (ideally just autowire a repo). In particular, this library sets itself up using an autoconfiguration class (enabled in `spring.factories`) and needs to disable other autoconfiguration classes to work (`DataSourceAutoConfiguration` and `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration`).

Is it possible to do this outside of the dependent project?

To make configuration as simple as possible I'd like to avoid putting excludes in the dependent project's `@SpringBootApplication` annotation or its `spring.autoconfigure.exclude` property.

**Update**:

On my @Configuration I have tried adding the annotations:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

this causes

> IllegalStateException: Configuration problem: A circular @Import has
>   been detected

and

```
@ImportAutoConfiguration(exclude={
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Which simply does nothing.

Comment: can't you use `@AutoConfigureBefore(...)`? Your custom autoconfiguration probably provides beans like datasource and so... Spring boot autoconfig won't interfere afterwards.

Comment: I really need to disable them, the purpose is to be able to create a project and include multiple of these data access libraries as dependencies. I'll get unsatisfied dependency issues if there are multiple beans of the same type on the classpath. Yes, I could use primary on one of the libraries but there's no guarantee I'll be using that library in each project. I've successfully set it up where each library has a "primary" config and a "secondary" config (for when a datasource already exists) but the code duplication is nasty.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's a very handy interface called `AutoConfigurationImportFilter`, which decides on which auto-configuration should be loaded. This is also how `@ConditionalOnClass` annotation works.

In your library, add the following class:

```
public class MyExclusionFilter
        implements AutoConfigurationImportFilter {

    private static final Set<String> SHOULD_SKIP = new HashSet<>(
            Arrays.asList("org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration",
                    "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration"));

    @Override
    public boolean[] match(String[] classNames, AutoConfigurationMetadata metadata) {
        boolean[] matches = new boolean[classNames.length];

        for(int i = 0; i< classNames.length; i++) {
            matches[i] = !SHOULD_SKIP.contains(classNames[i]);
        }
        return matches;
    }
}
```

This class needs to be registered in `spring.factories` to work. Add the following line in the library into `META-INF/spring.factories`:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter=com.mycompany.db.MyExclusionFilter
```

You don't need to make any changes to the dependent project. Just add the library as a dependency and the auto-configuration you specified won't be loaded for the whole application.

**NOTE:** You can add more than one import filter, only the auto-configuration classes not filtered in **all** import filters will get loaded.

For details, see the source code of `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector#filter` and `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition.java` classes.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem! The only issue is that it breaks `@DataJpaTest` test classes, for me using `@SpringBootTest` instead is an option since my libraries are fairly small. Do you have suggestions for getting `@DataJpaTest` to work when `@SpringBootTest` isn't an option / is too slow?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only thing comes to my mind involves creating a Test configuration which defined the beans that `@DataJpaTest` requires. However this begs for some testing.

Comment: Figured it out, even with the filter you can still import the configurations. So adding `@Import({DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})` does the trick when using `@DataJpaTest`.

Answer (score 2):

you can exclude then via

`@SpringBootApplication(exclude= {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class}))`

but you could exclude them in your `@Configuration` by adding
`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude= {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should've mentioned that I've tried the latter. Unfortunately, it causes an IllegalStateException with "Configuration problem: A circular @Import has been detected"

Comment: hmm, correct. I tested it in combination with _spring.factories_ and got same exception...