# Disabling a DatabaseInitializerDetector in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am defining my own Liquibase auto configuration to manage multitenancy, which involves a prototype `SpringLiquibase` bean:

```java
@Bean
@Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
SpringLiquibase tenantCreatedLiquibase(String tenantId) {
    // construct a SpringLiquibase instance
}
```

The `tenantCreatedLiquibase` prototype bean is instantiated at runtime via an [`ObjectProvider<SpringLiquibase>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22184027/150884).

But [`LiquibaseDatabaseInitializerDetector`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/liquibase/LiquibaseDatabaseInitializerDetector.java) creates a dependency from `jdbcTemplate` on my `tenantCreatedLiquibase` bean.  The ApplicationContext fails to load because the `tenantCreatedLiquibase` prototype bean requires a `tenantId` argument.

How can I disable the `LiquibaseDatabaseInitializerDetector`?  Or otherwise work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to [exclude any auto configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50565367/150884) that references `DatabaseInitializationDependencyConfigurer`.  In my case, that meant excluding `JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration` and `SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration` (in addition to `LiquibaseAutoConfiguration`, which is excluded because I provide my own custom replacement).

I'd still prefer direct control over the registration of `DatabaseInitializerDetector`s, but I'm not sure that's possible.